# Please solve javaFX issue

Tags: java, javafx, scene

Please help me to change gif file in javaFX ImageView and then switch to another scene after the gif is played once.
When i do it like

```
i.setImage(url);
window.setScene(s);
```

the switch is done immediately. I don't see the gif shown on the screen.
When i use

```
Thread.sleep(time),
```

between first two statements, the delay is realized, but gif does not change.
How is it done correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
i.setImage(url);
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(time));
pause.setOnFinished(e -> window.setScene(s));
pause.play();
```

You should never call `Thread.sleep(...)` on the FX Application Thread: it will prevent the UI from being rendered.